# radio buttons ripple effect hide on page load every time

Tags: html, css

I have added ripple effects to the radio buttons in my code, it is working well when selecting a radio button but I am trying to avoid the ripple effects showing on page/modal load. Is it possible to hide that ripple on page-load? For the checkbox it is working fine, but for the radio button it is not working – and shows the ripple on page-load – can any one offer a solution?

```css
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  /* display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px; */
}

.form-check-inline .form-check-input {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox label {
  position: relative;
  /* padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px; */
}


/* ripple
 */

.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-left: -37px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  background: #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  transform: scale(0);
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rippleDuplicate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.checkbox input+label:after {
  animation: ripple .4s ease-out;
}


/* to re-trigger the animation with just CSS, we need to duplicate the keyframes
 */

.checkbox input:checked+label:after {
  animation-name: rippleDuplicate;
}


/* fixes initial animation run, without user input, on page load.
 */

.checkbox label:after {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox input:focus+label:after {
  visibility: visible;
}


/*-------------radio ------------*/

@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 28px;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before,
input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #1565C0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #fff;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  top: 49%;
  left: 9px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #3f51b552;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-image: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -moz-animation: ripple 1s none;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1s none;
  animation: ripple 1s none;
}

.custom-control-inline {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-check form-check-inline checkbox checkbox-warning checkbox-inline pl-0 text-left">
  <input _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-check-input" id="check1" name="enquiry" type="checkbox">
  <label _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-check-label label-font" for="inlineCheckbox1">Closed Enquiries</label>
</div>
<br>
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-3 text-right po-list-radio">
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input" id="valid" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
    <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="valid">Valid</label>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input" id="expired" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
    <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="expired">Expired</label>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input" id="all" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
    <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="all">All</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

To reiterate: for the checkbox it is working, but not for the radio button; every time the page is initially loaded the ripple is happening, and I want to see it only after a user clicks on the radio button, not on page-load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your ripple effect is done in:

```
input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  background: #3f51b552;
  ...
```

you can set that background color to empty CSS variable so on load it wont show:

```
input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  background: var(--c, );
  ...
```

and then on click set that variable back to color with javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   this.nextElementSibling.style.setProperty("--c", "#3f51b552")
  })
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  /* display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px; */
}

.form-check-inline .form-check-input {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox label {
  position: relative;
  /* padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px; */
}


/* ripple
 */

.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-left: -37px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  background: #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  transform: scale(0);
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rippleDuplicate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.checkbox input+label:after {
  animation: ripple .4s ease-out;
}


/* to re-trigger the animation with just CSS, we need to duplicate the keyframes
 */

.checkbox input:checked+label:after {
  animation-name: rippleDuplicate;
}


/* fixes initial animation run, without user input, on page load.
 */

.checkbox label:after {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox input:focus+label:after {
  visibility: visible;
}


/*-------------radio ------------*/

@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 28px;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before,
input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #1565C0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #fff;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  background: var(--c, );
  top: 49%;
  left: 9px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-image: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -moz-animation: ripple 1s none;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1s none;
  animation: ripple 1s none;
}

.custom-control-inline {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-check form-check-inline checkbox checkbox-warning checkbox-inline pl-0 text-left">
  <input _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-check-input" id="check1" name="enquiry" type="checkbox">
  <label _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-check-label label-font" for="inlineCheckbox1">Closed Enquiries</label>
</div>
<br>
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-3 text-right po-list-radio">
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input" id="valid" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
    <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="valid">Valid</label>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input" id="expired" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
    <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="expired">Expired</label>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input" id="all" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
    <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="all">All</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ...is it possible to do only with css...i want to apply this feature on entire all the pages ...so please give me any help whether if it is possible with css

Comment: @shivakrishna I don't know any other way but I'm not expert in CSS, and this is simplest way... There is no way you can say in CSS alone "do not do on load"... And you can apply this function on all pages same way you are including CSS on all pages...